# Android - optimization of animating lot of views at once

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

In my game, I have a 4x4 grid of TextViews, each displaying one letter, arranged in a TableLayout.
I'd like to implement a "rotate 90 degrees clockwise" feature, and I'd like the grid to rotate, but I want the letters to stay upright.

It could be achieved by applying a 0 to 90 degree rotation on the TableLayout and another 0 to -90 degrees animation on each TextView. Then it will appear as if the letters are still oriented upwards, because the grid will be rotated from 0 to 90 degrees, and the TextViews' animation will cancel the rotation, as it's the exact opposite.

It works, but the animation is choppy on low-end devices and that doesn't look good. Is there something I can do to improve the animation performance, as I'm animating 17 views at once now. Is there some trick I might employ, like disabling antialiasing or setting lower color depth for the duration of animation (on slower devices)? Or is there some way to glue the 16 TextViews together and let Android do only one animation on this glued view?

[image]

Comment: Nice one. I think you want to implement the same effect that available in the Word Hero Game in Google Play. Let me try for it and i will put answer shortly.